# upload files to a cloud account 

Tags: java, cloud

i need to develop an application which will peridiocally upload files from my local machine to a cloud account(cloudme account)periodically.I tried this with Java and apache commons.but i couldnt.What technology i follow.Where can i find tutorials for this?pls help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** I always prefer `Apache's common libs`

I am also attaching my program which i used to upload and download song to ftp server using the apache's common lib

**Uploading :**

```
public void goforIt(){


        FTPClient con = null;

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("192.168.2.57");

            if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
                in.close();
                if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }
```

**Dowloading:**

```
public void goforIt(){
    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("192.168.2.57");

        if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("vivekm4a.m4a", out);
            out.close();
            if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("download result","failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String filename = "D:/Task/try.txt";
              System.out.println(client.storeFile("/root/try.txt", fis));
            fis.close(); client.storeFile always returns false for me..can u help?

Comment: My above code is from the production network, and its totally a working one.. Yes i have changed the IP addr, Username , Passwd for security reasons... You will have to use the correct IP or the FTP site name, then your usename and password, check all these details and yes you should also check that the file you are tyring to upload is present in it defined path and in proper format.. FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE is used when you need to send multimedia files like music,pics, audio etc....

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use WebDAV because cloudme supports that way.
There are also some java libs out there